# context.marshal_as is taking longer to execute each time it is called

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, marshalling, unmanaged

I have a debug function to export some images to hard disk, they are inside an unmanaged C++ dll. The function has two parameters that are marshaled into a single string for the complete file name. This function is called a lot of times. While executing the application I noticed that it becomes slower over time and I traced it back to this function (thanks to SlimTune!). If I leave the marshaling code but I comment out this line:

```
std::string completeFileName = m_csTempFolder + stdSubFolderName + stdFileName + ".bmp";
```

replacing it by:

```
std::string completeFileName = "C:\\Users\\pedro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\BatchProc64\\test.bmp";
```

I don't have the problem any more. It looks that the issue is with mixing the just marshaled strings with a string constant, into a new string. Anyone can explain this?
The app used memory remains stable, no app crash.
I'm using Visual Studio 2008 with .NET 3.5
Thanks in advance!

The start of the function code is below:

```
// Export the 32 bit buffer into a 8 bit buffer, then write it into a file, used for trace image generation (app debug)
void CMtxSurface::ExportTraceImage32bit(System::String^ subFolderName, System::String^     fileName, MIL_ID img32bit)
{
// The [Conditional("_TRACE_")] doesn't work in C++ compiler so we need to use ifdef...
#ifdef _TRACE_

marshal_context context;
std::string stdSubFolderName = context.marshal_as<std::string>(subFolderName);
std::string stdFileName = context.marshal_as<std::string>(fileName);

std::string completeFileName = m_csTempFolder + stdSubFolderName + stdFileName + ".bmp";
//  std::string completeFileName = "C:\\Users\\pedro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\BatchProc64\\test.bmp";
```

Comment: Maybe one of the strings becomes longer and longer?

Comment: No, all debug files are created ok, no app used memory increase over time... this is really strange, it looks like an issue from string manipulation internals.

Comment: If I do it like this is even worst! marshal_context context; 
System::String^ topName = subFolderName + fileName + ".bmp"; 
std::string stdTopName = context.marshal_as<std::string>(topName); std::string completeFileName = m_csTempFolder + stdTopName;

Comment: Well, the real problem is here: std::wstring wfilename(completeFileName.begin(), completeFileName.end()); I need to convert the string to a wstring. Even thought the completeFileName is a local variable, it gets longer and longer over time.